# vba split() not working in Mac Word 2004

Tags: mac, ms-office

I was trying to run a Word macro on a Mac. That macro contains the `split()` function. When I run this it is throwing an error saying function or sub not defined.

```
StrArr = Split(InputString, ":", -1, vbTextCompare)
```

I searched on the Internet and found that Mac Word 2004 is supported by VBA 5 and `split()` is introduced in VBA 6 only. I'm unable to find the proper solution for this, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Office for Mac 2004 is too old. You need to upgrade to Office 2011, which has the function you want:

> Office for Mac 2011 comes with VBA 6.5, ported from Office for Windows.
>   [Source](http://store.apple.com/us/question/answers/product/H2439LL/A?pqid=QCUHC94F4CDP9PHJJTKYFC4T4HP7TTJPT) - Apple Store Q & A

(I'm assuming VBA 6.5 didn't remove the `split()` function from 6.0.)